# Review audit failed for system verification POST

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, vote-to-reopen

I have following fishing POST from system for Validation (I am checking question carefully before vote):

[How to build a web app on tomcat? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443217/how-to-build-a-web-app-on-tomcat)

I have suggested "Leave Open". and system through message "Review audit failed"

***Why I suggest it to "Leave Open":***

Because this question has a valid answer and appreciation comment which is accepted by user.

**Question :**

Please suggest what I also consider before voting this type of posts.

Comment: first you are saying you are checking the question (clicking thru to it) to see if you should Leave it Open. You will notice 4 downvotes, potential gibberish in question, and that it is not even open. Yet you said Leave it Open

Answer (score 8):

That question is atrocious. It has no really clear problem statement and shows no real effort to find anything before coming to SO. Its basicly asking to teach him the very basic functionality of the program. The close reason is "unclear what you are asking" and thats exactly right, the question is deliberately unclear.

The next bombshell, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33443715/5389107) consists mainly of a link to a youtube tutorial, and to add insult to injury its a mobile link, too.

In conclusion. Not only was this question rightfully closed, the answer is low quality too, and even though its accepted, of at best very dubious use to future readers.

Also, if you actually clicked on the Question before voting on it, you would have noticed that several things mismatch:

1. The timestamp. Your audit probably said it was asked recently, yet it was asked 23 days ago.
2. The votes. Your audit probably showed neutral votes (none) on the Question, yet its at -6 atm.
3. The fact that its not open. Your audit didn't show that, but the question is obviously already closed, with a big banner at the bottom (which you must've scrolled down to to find the answer that was accepted) and a [closed] in the title.

In conclusion, either your examining was not very thorough at all or you didn't click the question link like you said you did.

Comment: Magisch thanks for expiation. Mentioned question in my post marked as "unclear what you're asking" but @Kaputnik120 answer this question and answer was accepted by @user3517188 with comment so i marked it "Leave Open"  . `same situation with this question and your answer(my question is marked as duplicate and your answer with 5 upvotes)`.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK a duplicate mark is not an unclear what you are asking mark. Duplicate means this question has been asked (and answered) before and unclear what you are asking means its impossible to give a useful or relevant answer to this question. You are mixing these up.

Answer (score 2):

As has been commented, if you actually opened the question, you'd have seen it was *closed*, with a couple of downvotes.

Yet you chose *"Leave open"*

Next time, I'm guessing you need to look at the question a little... better. Basically, pay more attention.